# How to make calculations in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
i = 3;
j = 2;

function domath(x) {
    i = 4;
    j = 1;
    return i*x + j;
}

j = domath(i) - j;
alert(j); //expected result = 11

k = domath(i) + j;
alert(k); //expected result = 15
```

The above JavaScript code does not return the expected results (as indicated by the comments in the code). Please correct the code for me anyone ?

Comment: Your not actually decalring them anywhere var i = 3 for example!

Comment: First thing: scoping. Unless you declare a `var`, the variable is created global. That's a bad thing, and not allowed in strict mode.

Comment: `//expected result = 11` is wrong, using variable scoping

Answer (score 3):

As you're not using `var` , the variables `i` and `j` you're defining in the first lines are actually the same variable as you define in your `domath()` function...

try this :

```
i = 3;
j = 2;

function domath(x) {
    var i = 4;
    var j = 1;
    return i*x + j;
}

j = domath(i) - j;
alert(j); //expected result = 11

k = domath(i) + j;
alert(k); //expected result = 15
```

P.S : it could be a good idea to vary your variable name in order to make your code more readable

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variables using `var`:

```
var i = 3;
var j = 2;

function domath(x) {
  var i = 4;
  var j = 1;
  return i * x + j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a really nasty way to do things.

I would personally do something like:

```
var v1;
var v2;

function math(x){ //do math here then return}
alert(math(1))
```

If you really have to use the same varible every where at least do it like:

```
var i = 3;
var j = 2;

function domath(x) {
var i = 4;
var j = 1;
return i*x + j;
}
```

Also meaningful varibles names will keep you on a good track and using var and not global will also help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 3;
var j = 2;

function domath(x) {
    var i = 4;
    var j = 1;
    return i*x + j;
}

var x = domath(i) - j; // overwriting J will change your next expected result
alert(x); //expected result = 11

var k = domath(i) + j;
alert(k); //expected result = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're overwriting global variables, i.e. screwing up your math:

```
j = domath(i) - j;
```

This expression is evaluated from left to right. The call to `domath()` will assign new values to `i` and `j`, so the effective code here would be this:

```
j = (i = 4) * 3 + 1 - 1;
```

So once this is done, `j` will be set to `12`, which is indeed not `11`. In addition, `i` will have a value of `4`.

To use local variables within your function, you'll have to redeclare them, essentially hiding the global variables being outside this scope:

```
function domath(x) {
    var i = 4;
    var j = 1;
    return i * x + j;
}
```

This time, the first assignment will be resolved to this, because `domath()` won't touch `i` and `j` assigned outside:

```
j = 4 * 3 + 1 - 2
```

Once this i done, `j` will be set to `11`, just as expected.

---

To avoid such issues, it's good practice to always use `var` when defining new variables (which you'll have to do when wanting to write `strict` code anyway), and not to use such short, not-telling variable names. I'd consider limiting the use of one-character variable names to iterators and other things with very limited scope. Never for something being global.